# Copyrighting a website

Tags: copyright, internet, licensing

I have a website that I want to publish, so I guess it's about time I get it copyrighted. The question is how?

I've heard I can do it through **[www.creativecommons.org](http://www.creativecommons.org)**

Here is what I found:

> Copyright is created automatically. In Cyprus as well as in the
>   European Union and in most countries there is no process of
>   registering and certifying copyright.  In case of infringement of
>   copyright, however, many are the ways which can witness and evidence
>   in court the ownership of copyright.
>   – [*http://ipcyprus.com/faq/*](http://ipcyprus.com/faq/#1c)

So does that mean I can't get the content of my website copyrighted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A website itself cannot be copyrighted, but the content on it is. Copyright protection is automatic: when you write something, it is protected by copyright law, and that protection persists when you put it on a website. If you intend to sue someone for infringement of copyright, you may have to register the copyright (details depend on national law). Creative Commons is not a way of protecting your intellectual property, it is a way of selectively removing copyright protection (by granting permission to copy, under certain circumstances).

In some countries, such as [Cyprus](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/text.jsp?file_id=126085), registration is not required; also, infringement is a criminal offense subject to a prison term up to 2 years and a fine up to 1500 pounds for a first offense. There are various differences between Cypriot and US law in terms of the registration, but basically the protection in the US is more limited for unregistered works. Under Article 4, as long as you are a citizen or resident of Cyprus, you are entitled to protection in Cypriot court.

Comment: How do I register the copywrite? preferably free.

Comment: Assuming this is the US, here is how: https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-register.html. There is no option for free registration. This page is tailored to registering online material: https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ66.pdf

Comment: thanks for the info, I can't seem to find a similar page for Cyprus..., is there a specific government website I have to go to?

Comment: Most nations do not require registration and do not maintain registers - the US is an outlier here.